# SWI-Prolog fails when declaring module-localized operators

Tags: swi-prolog

When declaring module-localized operators with precedences > 1000 the latest versions of SWI-Prolog (e.g. 8.2.1) fail when modules are dynamically loaded because of "conflicting" declarations. Take for example `test.pl`:

```
:- module(test, [rule/1]).
:- use_module([library(lists),library(qsave)]).
test:set_ops :- test:op(1098, fx, prefix).
:- test:set_ops.
:- initialization test:set_ops.
rule(prefix F) :-
  atom(F), !,
  op(100, fy, F).
rule(A) :-
  atom(A),
  user:qsave_program(A, [goal = true, op = save]).
```

Note that `prefix` clashes with `prefix` in `library(lists)`. However, `prefix` is an operator declared in the module scope of `test`. The scoping does not appear to work:

```
?- [test].
?- apropos(append).
ERROR: /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/library/lists.pl:40:16: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: prolog_stack:find_subgoal/3: Unknown procedure: prolog_stack:nth1/3
```

Invoking `user:qsave_program/2` fails, despite the fact that `library(qsave)` was already imported:

```
:- rule(saveme).
ERROR: /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/library/lists.pl:40:16: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/library/lists.pl:40:16: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/library/lists.pl:76:
ERROR:    Domain error: `module_file' expected, found `'/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/library/lists.pl''
```

Any ideas how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `test:op(1098, fx, prefix)` does NOT place the `prefix` operator in the `test` module, but `op(1098, fx, test:[prefix])` does. This was not at all clear from the SWI-Prolog 8.2.1 documentation.

The corrected program:

```
:- module(test, [rule/1]).
:- use_module([library(lists),library(qsave)]).
set_ops :- op(1098, fx, test:[prefix]).
:- set_ops.
:- initialization set_ops.
rule(prefix F) :-
  atom(F), !,
  op(100, fy, F).
rule(A) :-
  atom(A),
  qsave_program(A, [goal = true, op = save]).
```

However, there appears to be a bug that "forgets" predicates after `qsave_program/2` is invoked (via `rule(saveme)`):

```
?- [test].
?- rule(saveme).
?- apropos(append).
ERROR: Unknown procedure: apropos/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Well, at least everything else seems to work as long as `qsave_program/2` is not used, i.e. when not invoking `rule(saveme)`.